# gettting different output in bubble sort in c

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

Hey I am a newbie in dsa so I was learning bubble sort but my output is different please see my code below

output should be: `7,12,21,70,83`
my output is: `12,7,70,21,83`
which is incorrect

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubble_sort(int duparray[], int num) {
    int temp, i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) { // i means number of passes
        for (j = 0; j < num - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (duparray[i] > duparray[i + 1]) {
                temp = duparray[i];
                duparray[i] = duparray[i + 1];
                duparray[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", duparray[i]);
    }
}

void display(int duparray[], int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", duparray[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[5] = { 70, 12, 7, 83, 21 };
    int n = 5;
    display(array, n);
    printf("\n");
    bubble_sort(array, n);
    // display(array, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the for loops should look like

```
for( i=0;i<num-1;i++){// i means number of passes
    for( j=0;j<num-1-i;j++){
        if(duparray[j]>duparray[j+1]){
            temp=duparray[j];
            duparray[j]=duparray[j+1];
            duparray[j+1]=temp;

        }
    }
```

That is use `j` and `j+1` as the indexes for the elements that are being compared and swapped. Note that `i` doesn't change in the inner loop, so your code was just comparing the same two elements repeatedly.

If you will make the changes then the output will be

```
70 12 7 83 21 
7 12 21 70 83
```